# How to have this formatted data return empty given this is VLOOKUP + TEXT + QUERY in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, google-sheets-formula, formula, google-query-language

This is the formula, currently. It outputs `12/30/1899`, but it actually returns 0 and since `TEXT()` is forcing it into a data, this is how it shows. How to have this `ARRAYFORMULA()` populate the values and empty when there is no date?

Formula:

```
=IF(I4<>"","Factura (USD)",
  ({"Wire Transfer Date";
        arrayformula(IFNA(
            TEXT(
            VLOOKUP($J$10:$J900,
              query(Datasets!S3:U,"select S, U"),2,0),
            "mm/dd/yyyy")
         )
       )
    }
  )
)
```

Current output, which should be empty instead:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=IF(I4<>"", "Factura (USD)", {"Wire Transfer Date"; 
 ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(IFNA(TEXT(VLOOKUP($J$10:$J900, 
 QUERY(Datasets!S3:U, "select S,U"), 2, ), "mm/dd/yyyy")), "12/30/1899", ))})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought of replacing whichever year would come up that was smaller than 2022... Thank you!